# retriving image from from database through mysqli using php is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to upload and retrieving image from mysql in php. the upload part is working fine while when i am trying to retrieve a image it giving me error. i have try different logic's but i think i am not doing the write one :(. 
connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "hightech"; 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

uploading

```
//file upload start
    $file_result="";

        if ($_FILES["add_img"]["error"]>0){
            $file_result .= "No File uploaded or invalid File";
            $file_result .="Error Code: " . $_FILES["sound_input"]["error"] ."<br>";  
        }  
        else {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["add_img"]["tmp_name"],
                    "C:/wamp/www/hightech/images/uploads/" 
                    . $_FILES["add_img"]["name"]);
            $file_result .= "File upload Successful!" ;        
        }
        echo $file_result;

        //file upload end
```

saving file name other data on database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO desktop(type,name,company,item_img,price,point1,point2,point3,point4,point5)
        VALUES ('$type','$itemname','$comp','$img','$price','$point1','$point2','$point3','$point4','$point5')";
$run=  $conn->query($sql);
```

retrieving image and other data from data base.

```
 <?php             
   $sql1="SELECTname,price,point1,point2,point3,
   point4,point5,item_img       
   FROM desktop WHERE company = 'Alienware' ";
    $sel_query1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
        if($sel_query1 == FALSE) { 
        die(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel_query1)) {
        echo'<div>'.
           '<img src="C:/wamp/www/hightech/images/uploads/'.row['item_img']. '"/>'.
           '<span>'.
             '<ul>'.
                '<li  id="item_name" style="color:red">'.$row['name'].'</li>'.
                '<li>'.$row['point1'].'</li>'.
                '<li>'.$row['point2'].'</li>'.
                '<li>'.$row['point3'].'</li>'.
                '<li>'.$row['point4'].'</li>'.
                '<li>'.$row['point5'].'</li>'.
            '<ol style="color:red;padding-left:1;font-size:18">'.$row['price'].'</ol>'.
            '<ol style="padding-left:110"> <a>'.'<img src="http://localhost/hightech/images/add.png" />'. '</a></ol>
             </ul>
          </span>

       </div>';
    }
?>
```

> ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\hightech\admin\admin_desktop.php on line 85

Line 85 is

```
<img src="C:/wamp/www/hightech/images/uploads/'.row['item_img']. '"/>
```

Comment: What is the error, you are given?

Comment: this `SELECTname` MySQL should be telling you something about that. Edit: Oh, I know why it's not, because `mysqli_error()` has no parameter. `// TODO: better error handling` no better time than now. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: then you're doing `src="C:/wamp/www/hightech/images/uploads/` and `src="http://localhost/...`

Comment: At $sql1 you missed a space SELECT name. Maybe this is your error since we do not know your error...

Comment: no its still not working..

Comment: You missed a .$row ['item_img'] !!!

Comment: not working, isn't much of a statement as to why it's failing. Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $sql1 you missed a space SELECT name. Maybe this is your error since we do not know your error...

And You missed a .$row ['item_img']

Edit. There is also a space on the same line after the bracket.

I am not sure but aren't there some dots missing at the end of echo part?

Comment: is there a dot after $

Comment: Uh. Ihm I am sorry but this app is going me crazy. It never shows me newest comments or answers even when i reload.

Comment: if anything, fixing the syntax for the `[` thing, would trigger an undefined constant row notice

Comment: does i am using the write syntax to display a img from database?

Comment: Uhm the point is in front of dollar sign. Srr. Like your other rows. I do not know if you need an extra space between.

Comment: sir i know i have fix it with .$row['item_img'] but its stil giving me this error      ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\hightech\admin\admin_desktop.php on line 85

Comment: Show us the code on line 85+. Update it in your question post please

Comment: I am guessing it is just a simple ;

Comment: Show us some more. Not only one single line. Some lines before and after that. Maybe line 80 to 90

Comment: Please provide the additional code and update your previous code with the fixes.

Answer (score 1):

You just try the below code.

```
  <?php
       $sql1="SELECT fields_you want FROM `tablename` WHERE YOUR_CONDITION ";
       $sel_query1= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
        if($sel_query1 == FALSE) 
        { 
          die(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
        }

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel_query1)) 
      {
        echo'<div>'.
       '<img src="images/uploads/'.$row['IMAGE_FIEDL_NAME']."/>'.'</div>';        
      }
  ?>
```

You just ignore your whole path.If your ***"images"*** and ***"uploads"*** folder is in the same directory of your project,you just give your path detail like ***"images/uploads"***. 
You can use this folder structure for your uploading process also. It's enough. 
It will display your images.I tried it.It's working!! You try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use dot Before single quote in your sql statement like "'".$type."'", if the problem is in the sql may be it will resolve your problem